# Mathematical tools for emergent structures in the Wolfram Physics project?

Tags: complex-systems, emergent-properties

Wolfram Physics project https://www.wolframphysics.org/ demonstrates how complex structures emerge from the simple graph-like structures and rules. Graphs can be used as the microstructure, in fact - entire Wolfram universa in just graph. My question is - what math tools, structures are used for the modelling of the emergent structure in Wolfram worlds? One can see that emergent structures are something like graphs as well, only with dense edges and fuzzy nodes. Or maybe there are nodes at all? Only dense geometric/topological structures?

It seems to me that currently Wolfram is content only with the visualization of the emergent structures and not with the efforts to describe them mathematically. But maybe still there are efforts to use math for the emergent structures in the Wolfram universes? What kind of math it is? Are there any examples?

I am interested in this emergence - how the transition happens from the graph structures to the emergent graph-like structures?

There are similar transitions from the micro-macro scales in other branches of physics as well, but always there is different math for different scales.

Comment: He has also published a somewhat mathematical paper (just see the Technical Documents section on the page you referred to). But I agree that it lacks rigor and references to established mathematical formalisms in physics.

Comment: Have a look at preprint paper titled "Some Relativistic and Gravitational Properties of the Wolfram Model" by Jonathan Gorard. Among other things, he gives a mathematical description of how Einstein's equations emerge from the wolfram model.

Comment: I don't want to offend Wolfram's work, which is great to some extent, however it seems that his work is more directly related to automaton theory and universal Turing machine, and as a consequence - more relationship to computer science than to physics. I don't say that universe can't be modelled as some sort of automaton, probably it can, but the main problem is that this approach is very weakly related to established Physics theories.

Comment: I have found good use of Wolfram's magnus opus as a door stop....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we are some of the few people on this forum interested in Wolfram Physics model? I have also just asked a question related to the hypergraph structures and how the 2d graphical representations of the nodes relate to their physical spatial distribution.
I discovered Stephen Wolfram and his model through  Youtube podcasts of Lex Fridman  where the two discuss about his theory. I recommend you check it too.

Comment: Sorry, but answers are not suitable places to connect research interests. They are supposed to be answers.